# Regular expression on a URL

Tags: regex

I need to be able to catch when the URL contains a image of multiple file types or follow this syntax.

http://localhost:8080/fdlic-web/webpic/101

Here is what i have so far.

```
(.*)(jpg|gif|png|bmp|jpeg|webpic/(\d+))$
```

Comment: your regex is kinda fine, only minor improvements can be done. What is your question?

Comment: is it working? what's the question?

Comment: What's the question? Does this regex not work for you? Please clarify...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good so far, just use less grouping and kick out the `.*`, you don't need it.

```
(?:webpic/\d+|gif|png|bmp|jpe?g)$
```

Actually, it's less ambiguous to delimit your directories/file types to prevent partial matches that yield false positives:

```
(?:/(?:webpic/\d+)|\.(?:gif|png|bmp|jpe?g))$
    ^                             ^
    | all path components here    |
         all file extensions here |
```